# How to automatically capture images as user moves down the iphone /ipad camera to make a panoroma like picture?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimageview, image-editing

I have an app where i scan the forms means i take its pictures and upload them . Now if the form is long so that the iphone /ipad camera could not take picture of entire form clearly. In that case i want the user to slowly move the camera down , so that continous images are taken until the whole form is looked or scanned . After that create a picture stitching all the frames together. I know there can be various ways of doing this manually like i can let user chose when to take pictures ad after merge them together.

But is there any way to do this automatically maybe some api etc. I mean automatically capture frames as user moves the camera down. After that i can merge the images together .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should capture video (the UIImagePickerController gives you a quick generic interface for this), then use MPMoviePlayerController to get images from the captured video.

MPMoviePlayerController provides requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:.

So...

1. write down the start time start = [NSDate date];
2. ask the user to pan over the document and to press the stop button when done (you can put some instruction right on the preview view using the cameraOverlayView property
3. bring up the picker and startVideoCapture
4. when imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: gets fired, write down the end time.
5. then, based on the interval between start and end, pick N times for images
6. build an MPMoviePlayerController and call requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:

You'll have N images to stitch.

Comment: Thanks it seems a great idea but i am using avcapture session to use camera and not mpmoviecontroller . Will this method work with avcapture method ???

Comment: Sure.  Whichever way you write the video data, you can still open it (and not play it back, just get thumbs) with MPMoviePlayerController.  You've got a lot done already.  Just begin at step 5.

Comment: Yeah i tried it and worked great but problem is how can i get proper images . For example i am making video of a long form. So when i have n number of images they should be different . I mean not repetetive text. So that when i stitch them .The final image should look like a complete form.i hope you understood ..

Comment: I think I understand: your image stitcher want's disjoint images, images that don't overlap.  (usually stitcher's want overlap, so they can figure out exactly how to combine using the overlapping pixels as a way to match).  But maybe your "stitcher" is just concatenation?

Comment: No I think you're stuck with two options:  use pixel matching to stitch, or make the user do the work to take non-overlapping photos that fully cover the doc.  If you make the user do the work, then you can't take the pics automatically (like with video), because the user needs to tell the app when the framing is ready.  Here's a UI idea in that case:  show the bottom part of the last image at the top of the screen, then put the photo preview right underneath.  then user will have a guide about where to frame the next img.

Comment: yeah i dont want repetative image parts or pixels. For example if a form has 15 questions. So when user scans the form it the thumnails should be different like first one will have ouestions (1-4), second one (5-12)and remaining  in the last . it should not be like first image have questions (1-4) , secong one have (2-8)or (7-10) .Every image must not contails othe images text or data so that when i combine all images it must gives a illusion that it was a complete form and not different images stiched together.

Comment: Yeah i know manual way is very easy as i can gives user 5 seconds to align the camera so that end result will be perfect and it is my last option if i coulnot do it automatically. Well thanks your idea worke great

Comment: you could use NSTimer to fire every 5 seconds, but user might not be ready at 5sec or be ready sooner.  If you're off either way, you'll annoy them.  Best of luck!